# How to organise the MYSQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I don't know a lot about MYSQL and am having trouble designing my database structure. I don't understand all the information given to me online too much jargon expecting me to understand other terms and ideas and do not want to take a course for this one job so I hope this is simple enough.

I want to create a list of files on a page. There should be 4 fields:

- **Name** - files title
- **Units** - which of the select units this file applies to (example: 27 or X1 or 10), I want to be able to add multiple units to some files.
- **Typeof** - What type of file it is (example: swf, pdf, url).
- **Project** - What project the file was produced for (example: sexual health, information literacy)
- **Outcomes** - This should be able to store the numbers 1-5 so one file may have (1,3 and 5)

The problem is how I want to use this data, I want to be able to first search through units and find a match say for unit 27, then I want to find each project in that unit and list the files within that project.

The problem is files may and should appear multiple times on the page because some files have multiple units but I cant think how to best do this, searching the index of a string seems messy.

To help visualise what I want here is an image of how the page will be structured: [how the page will be structured http://biteof.com/example.bmp](http://biteof.com/example.bmp)

Your help is much appreciated thanks.

What I have so far:

```
  name    text                       utf8_unicode_ci 
  typeof set('swf','fla','web','pdf') utf8_unicode_ci  No None                
  units text utf8_unicode_ci  No None                
  url text utf8_unicode_ci  No None                
  project set('sexual health','information literacy','experimental') utf8_unicode_ci  No None                
  outcomes text utf8_unicode_ci  No None
```

@Nick:

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM `repository` WHERE `units` = '27' LIMIT 0, 999 ";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()) ;
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$name=mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
$filetype=mysql_result($result,$i,"typeof");
$project=mysql_result($result,$i,"project");
$units=mysql_result($result,$i,"units");
$url=mysql_result($result,$i,"url");

echo "File name: ".$name."<br>";
echo "Units: ".$units."<br>";
echo "In project: ".$project."<br>";
echo "Url: ".$url."<br>";

$i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: What you're asking is not a specific question, it is a very broad question.

Comment: You will get better response if you add what you have actually done so far. Include your tables, the fields (and some data if possible, a few rows for each table).

Comment: Okay added my current structure, the problem with what I have now is the ability to add multiple units and repeat the file in each specific unit.

Comment: @Hogan No one hired me this is for my apprenticeship portfolio site, I have a lot of files to upload and sort that it is too much to list them by hand .etc - Shouldnt assume things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved :)

I decided to make a new table for each unit because the file may be the same across units but the outcomes are different. the rest of my database I kept the same and used php to sort the probably horribly structured db... here is my code if your interested:

```
<?php 
$table = array("301","302","310","311","25","26","27","28","29","1","2","3","4","8","10","X1","X2");
for ($a=0;$a<sizeof($table);$a++) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM `$table[$a]`";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()) ;
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num > 0) {
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/units_and_evidence/units/".$table[$a].".php");
$projects = array();
for ($b=0;$b<$num;$b++) {
$project=mysql_result($result,$b,"project");
array_push($projects, $project);
}
$unique_projects = array_unique($projects);
for($c=0;$c<sizeof($unique_projects);$c++) {
$project_string = ucfirst($unique_projects[$c]);
print ('<div class="project"><h3>'.$project_string.'</h3>');
for($d=0;$d<$num;$d++) {
$name=mysql_result($result,$d,"name");
$project=mysql_result($result,$d,"project");
$typeof=mysql_result($result,$d,"typeof");
$url=mysql_result($result,$d,"url");
$outcomes=mysql_result($result,$d,"outcomes");
if ($project == $unique_projects[$c]) {
$outcomes_array= array();
for ($e=0;$e<strlen($outcomes);$e++) {
array_push($outcomes_array, $outcomes[$e]);
}
rsort($outcomes_array);
if ($typeof == swf) {
$proj = str_replace(' ', '', $project); 
$file = str_replace(' ', '', $url); 
print ('<li><a href="flashdelivery.php?proj='.urlencode($proj).'&file='.urlencode($file).'" class="'.$typeof.'selector">');
}
else {
print ('<li><a href="'.$url.'" class="'.$typeof.'selector">');
}
for ($f=0;$f<sizeof($outcomes_array);$f++) {
  print ('<span class="n'.$outcomes_array[$f].'"></span>');
}
print ('&raquo; '.ucfirst($name).'</a></li>');
}
}
print ('</div>');
}
print ("</ul>");
}
}
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/footer.php"); 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

After reading your question a few times it seems that you understand how to build the tables, you just need help querying them. Do you have code you can share that you've tried?

You should probably do a table join.

Comment: Sort of but all the information i am seeing is saying this isn't going to work, not to use sets .etc use seperate tables but then I dont understand their examples or how to implement it... but this is all I have so far to output a piece of the table, not sure how to see what projects exist within a unit because if a unit has no files in say 'experimental' I don't want to then build the experimental area on the page. Edit: code wont fit in here check question at bottom for code.

Comment: It looks like you need to query for the project types, loop through the results and then do a nested loop to show the actual projects. There should be an intermediate table between outcomes and projects. It's really difficult to tell you how to do it.

Comment: I feel units is still wrong though, for example there is a unit called 310 and 10, because I want to store multiple units right now I must do an index of search but unit 10 will appear as an index of 310 currently. Say I looped through the results of project and stored each value in array (remove duplicates from array) then looped through the array to build the projects area under each unit and then performed a query on that unit and that project for each project sounds possible. But do you know a way around my units dilemma? Thanks for advice mate.